# Can't able to add new language(Thai) in Liferay DXP 7.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.2

I want to add a new language (Thai) in my Liferay DXP 7.2 but can't able to add. I have followed below steps:

1. Added mapping to web.xml file (`LIFERAY_HOME\tomcat-<version>\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF`)

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>I18n Servlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/th/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>I18n Servlet</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/th-TH/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. Added URL pattern to web.xml file (`LIFERAY_HOME\tomcat-<version>\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF`)

   ```
   <url-pattern>/th/c/portal/protected</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/th-TH/c/portal/protected</url-pattern>
   ```
3. I found 4 portal-ext.properties files (PROJECT_NAME\Config\local\portal-ext.properties, PROJECT_NAME\Config\dev\portal-ext.properties, PROJECT_NAME\Config\uat\portal-ext.properties, PROJECT_NAME\Config\prod\portal-ext.properties), added following locales in every files.

   ```
   locales=th,ar_SA,eu_ES,bg_BG,ca_AD,ca_ES,zh_CN,en,en_US,th_TH
   ```

Restarted the tomcat server but in Portal UI: Configuration > Settings > Languages it's still not showing on Available language's section

screenshot

[image]

Probably one more step is pending which is icon and `language_<langCode>.properties` files related changes. But still after completing the above steps I should able to find newly added language on settings available language list page on UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all steps you followed, new language should be displayed in "Control Panel" => "Configuration" => "Instance Settings" => "Localization" in "available" column.

You have to add it at instance level before adding it to a existing site.

More information see following pages:

- https://www.knowarth.com/here-is-how-to-add-new-language-support-to-liferay-7-1/
- https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/add-a-new-language-to-liferay-detailed-step-by-step-
- https://www.surekhatech.com/blog/new-language-support-in-liferay-dxp